# How do I code paths that are stored in database?

Tags: c#, directory, getfiles

I am learning to write a program to delete log files on servers that are older than specified days.  This program will be table based rather than server based.  Using UNC the paths for the directory of the log files are stored in the database.  I am learning about Directory.GetFiles() method and I'm not sure what the syntax would be the path.  I'm thinking it would be workList since it stores the paths.  Any help resolving this would be greatly appreciated.  My code is below.

```
//create list to store database contents
static List<LogData> GetWorkList()
{
    List<LogData> logDatas = new List<LogData>();
    LogData logData = new LogData();


    //execute sql query
    //execute database reader
    string sqlQuery = "Select daysToKeep, fileLocation, active from dbo.FileDeletion where fileLocation='@fileLocation';";
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery);
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read())
    {

        //make a logData, creating a new instance of a class
        logData = new LogData();

        //move stuff from reader into log data, and exp
        logData.DaysToKeep = Convert.ToInt32(reader["daysToKeep"]);
        logData.Active = Convert.ToBoolean(reader["active"]);
        logData.FileLocation = Convert.ToString(reader["fileLocation"]);


        //add logData to list
        logDatas.Add(logData);

    }

    return logDatas;
}

//Get active entries from table, call getWorkList
public static void WorkList(//Not sure of what path to use)
{   
    //get active entries

    List<LogData> workList = GetWorkList();

    foreach()
    {
        if(File.Exists()
        {

        }
    }

    //check to see if date created in directory is older that x number of days
    if(DateTime.Now.Subtract(dt).TotalDays <= 1)
    {
        log.Info("This directory is less than a day old");
    }
    //if file is older than x number of days
    else if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(dt).TotalDays <= //not sure of what variable or property to use)
    {
        File.Delete
    }
    //delete file
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what `I'm not sure what the syntax would be the path` means?  (You have `c:\temp\blah.log` and you want `c:\temp`  or `blah.log`)

Comment: There are multiple paths listed in the database in a column named "fileLocation".  I have attempted to code the program to store those "multiple" paths in a list.  The list holds the directory locations for all paths where log files reside.  So trying to use a straight path hard coded wouldn't work because I want it to loop through the list and check each file for daysToKeep, and if the file is older than daysToKeep, then delete the file.  I hope that is more clear.  I know what I want, just not sure how to get there

Comment: The problem I am having is that there is no example of what is stored in `fileLocation` nor have you given an example of what part of the value of `fileLocation` you want.

Comment: \\gts101server\sharedFolder\Program Files\User\Services\Log Files\Logs  With this path UNC is used by the program to go to whatever file location path is listed, regardless of what server it resides on.  Thereby eliminating the need to create an exe for each server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your fileLocation contains not just the path, but the filename as well, then the below should work.

```
//Get active entries from table, call getWorkList
public static void WorkList(//Not sure of what path to use)
{   
//get active entries

List<LogData> workList = GetWorkList();

foreach(var work in workList)
{
    if(File.Exists(work.fileLocation))
    {
        File.Delete(work.fileLocation);
    }
}

//check to see if date created in directory is older that x number of days
if(DateTime.Now.Subtract(dt).TotalDays <= 1)
{
    log.Info("This directory is less than a day old");
}
//if file is older than x number of days
else if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(dt).TotalDays <= //not sure of what variable or property to use)
{
    File.Delete
}
//delete file
```

}

Comment: Thanks Bill, at this point this is getting me in the right direction

Comment: You're welcome! If you have further examples, or information, we can get closer to what you need. The File class is pretty robust as is the Directory class. You can easily loop through the files in a directory to get what you need as well.

Answer (score 0):

> I am learning about Directory.GetFiles() method and I'm not sure what the syntax would be the path.

[Directory.GetFiles()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx) Appears to be pretty straight forward.

```
foreach (var myPath in pathsFromDatabase)
{
  string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(myPath)
  Console.WriteLine("Directory {0} contains {1} files.", myPath, files.Length);
}
```

Would print the number of files in each directory.

Comment: Thank yo for the offer of assistance.  It would be so straight forward if I could hard code the path.  There are multiple paths in workList so hard coding would not work because then I would have to hard code each path and there are multiple paths per server.

Comment: Changing a hardcoded value to a not hard coded value is 5 seconds worth of work in this case...

Comment: Ok, that is why I posted this comment.  I am learning how to do this.  Just stating it is 5 seconds worth of work is not helping learn how to do it.  Please give me an example

Comment: With all due respect, I could have put myPath in anywhere.  Your example leaves more questions than provides answers

Comment: I quoted your question at the top, which basically to me means `how do I use Directory.GetFiles()`.  First I provided you with an example of how it works (and a link to msdn).  Then I updated my answer to give an extremely SIMPLE example of how to through a list/array of strings that represent paths and run the method with each path.  If I am not providing enough information to help, it's because you're question is extremely vague in what you *actually need help with*.

Comment: Bill Hatter answered the question the best and pretty much got me where I need to be.  So he clearly understood my question and was able to provide a viable and working answer.  Thanks again though for trying

Comment: And yet his answer does not include Directory.GetFiles... the one thing you actually directly wanted an answer for.